# React styled components with themeContext

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React Header component in which I'm trying to get a theme value from the `ThemeContext.Consumer` and pass it into my `NavListItem`. It's currently working (sort of) but I'd like to only pass it once and have it applied globally. Instead of having to write `theme={theme.typography.navigation}` each time I use the styled component?

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import styled from "styled-components"

import ThemeContext from "../context/ThemeContext"

const Main = styled.header`
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
`

const NavWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
`

const NavListLeft = styled.ul`
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
`

const NavListItem = styled.li`
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-family: ${props => props.theme};
  font-size: 16px;
`

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {theme => (
      <Main>
        <NavWrapper>
          <NavListLeft>
            <NavListItem theme={theme.typography.navigation}>
              <Link style={{color: 'black'}}>Women</Link>
            </NavListItem>
            <NavListItem theme={theme.typography.navigation}>Men</NavListItem>
            <NavListItem theme={theme.typography.navigation}>Designers</NavListItem>
            <NavListItem theme={theme.typography.navigation}>Collection</NavListItem>
            <NavListItem theme={theme.typography.navigation}>Sale</NavListItem>
          </NavListLeft>
        </NavWrapper>
      </Main>
    )}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
)

Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `NavListItem` that consumes your theme.

```
const ThemedNavListItem = styled.li`
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.typography.navigation};
  font-size: 16px;
`

const NavListItem = props => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {theme => <ThemedNavListItem {...props} theme={theme} />}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
);

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <Main>
    <NavWrapper>
      <NavListLeft>
        <NavListItem>
          <Link style={{color: 'black'}}>Women</Link>
        </NavListItem>
        <NavListItem>Men</NavListItem>
        <NavListItem>Designers</NavListItem>
        <NavListItem>Collection</NavListItem>
        <NavListItem>Sale</NavListItem>
      </NavListLeft>
    </NavWrapper>
  </Main>
);
```

A simpler solution using `styled-components` [`ThemeProvider`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#themeprovider).

> A helper component for theming. Injects the theme into all styled
>   components anywhere beneath it in the component tree, via the context
>   API.

```
const NavListItem = styled.li`
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.typography.navigation};
  font-size: 16px;
`

const Header = ({ siteTitle }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Main>
      <NavWrapper>
        <NavListLeft>
          <NavListItem>
            <Link style={{color: 'black'}}>Women</Link>
          </NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>Men</NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>Designers</NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>Collection</NavListItem>
          <NavListItem>Sale</NavListItem>
        </NavListLeft>
      </NavWrapper>
    </Main>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

[image: Edit intelligent-leavitt-oqyod]